# Removing file permissions in python

Tags: python, file, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to remove file permissions in python. I am aware that the mode to do so is "000." However I'm seeing the removal of file permissions be done with flags as well such as "stat.S_IRWXO." Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong

```
import os
import stat

file_path = 'random file'

os.chmod(file_path, stat.S_IRWXO)
```

My attempt with the "000" mode:

```
import os
import stat

file_path = "C:\Script\poop.txt"

os.chmod(file_path, 000)
```

**EDIT**

Using subprocesses, I was able to resolve the problem. I have not read the full documentation to know if chmod is not fully compatible with Windows, but it seems like it is at the very least, severely limited. Below is the code to use Window's "icacls" command to set permission. This is much more efficient.

```
import subprocess

file_path = r'C:\Script\poop.txt'

subprocess.check_output(['icacls.exe',file_path,'/deny','everyone:(f)'],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

**SOURCES**

[calling windows' icacls from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421302/calling-windows-icacls-from-python)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod

Comment: have you tried to use `os.chmod(file_path, 000)` ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. I'm trying to modify a simple text file, if that helps

Comment: Windwos doesn't have ``chmod``.

Comment: @Psytho are there any other methods then that I can use to do this?

Comment: Strangely enough it is possible to use ``os.chmod`` on WIndows (``chmod`` in terminal throws an error). YOu have to use double ``\\`` in the file path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting folder permissions in Windows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168110/setting-folder-permissions-in-windows-using-python)

Comment: @kabanus technically. I will put my solution in my original post

Comment: Better to post an answer of your own, if the dupe doesn't fit. This will benefit future readers. You can accept it in a day.

Comment: Side note: file permissions are usually written in octal (base 8). While it makes no difference for `000`, in general mode value in a program must be written like `0o644` or `0o22`.

Answer (score 3):

This string:

```
file_path = "C:\Script\poop.txt"
```

is un-escaped. Thus the path becomes something like "C:Scriptpoop.txt". Use a raw string:

```
 file_path = r"C:\Script\poop.txt"
```

or use `\\` instead of `\`.

Comment: Also, "Scriptpoop" is an adequate name for temporary files created by a script and not cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module as an general solution:

```
import subprocess

file_path = 'file.txt'
subprocess.call(['chmod', '000', file_path])
```

terminal output `ls -la`:

```
-r--r--r-- 1 kernel 197121     0 Mar  8 10:29 file.txt
```

Comment: The OP has a Windows machine. Or at least it looks that way.

Comment: this code was tested in windows machine with git-bash installed. Try to [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod) about windows support

Answer (score 1):

On ms-windows, you can only use `os.chmod` to set and remove the read-only bit. All others bits are ignored.

Basically, file permissions work differently on ms-windows than on POSIX operating systems. You will have to modify Access Control Lists using win32 API calls. To do that from within Python, you will need [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).